# Pass string and temporary array into sub in 1 line?

Tags: perl

I made a subroutine that I want to pass a string and an array into:

```
sub pass_in {
    my ($str, $array) = @_;
    for my $e (@$array) {
        print "I see str $str and list elem: $e\n";  
    }
    return 0;
}

my @temp_arr =  qw(A B C D E);
my $str = "hello";
pass_in( $str, \@temp_arr );
```

This works fine, but I don't want to have to create a `temp_arr`. Is it possible to do?

Doesn't work:

```
pass_in( $str, qw(A B C D E));
```

Also doesn't work:

```
pass_in( $str, \qw(A B C D E));
```

I don't want to create a temporary variable.

Answer (score 7):

You can use square brackets to create a reference to an array:

```
pass_in( $str, [qw(A B C D E)]);
```

[perldoc perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Making-References)

Comment: Or you can assign `my ( $str, @array ) = @_` and pass in the list of elements `pass_in ( $str, qw ( A B C D E ) );`

Answer (score 2):

In order to pass an in array, you have must an array to pass!

`qw()` does not create an array. It just puts a bunch of scalars on the stack. That for which you are looking is `[ ]`. It conveniently creates an array, initializes the array using the expression within, and returns a reference to the array.

```
pass_in( $str, [qw( A B C D E )] );
```

Alternatively, you could rewrite your subroutine to accept a list of values.

```
sub pass_in {
    my $str = shift;
    for my $e (@_) {
        print "I see str $str and list elem: $e\n";  
    }

    return 0;
}

pass_in( "hello", qw( A B C D E ) );
```